# How to integrate Telerilk Reporting in ASP.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net, reporting, telerik

i would like to use Telerik Reporting in ASP.NET MVC2 ...

how can i call or show my report in mvc view

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ["Using Telerik Web ReportViewer in ASP.NET MVC application"](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/reporting/general/using-telerik-web-reportviewer-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx) code library entry.

Comment: hi korchev thanks for reply i try this but i cant understand how can i view my report in my asp.net mvc2 viewer(index.aspx)

Comment: have you any other example which just show my hello world in report and in my asp.mvc2 viwer(index.aspx)

Comment: This is the only application that I know of. I think it shows exactly what you need - the report viewer hosted in an MVC view.